# Bash redirecting the output form passwd to be used by grep to verify a correct password change

Tags: bash, redirect, grep, passwd

as the title says I am trying to get the output when running passwd to verify that the password had changed correctly and by stopping passwd from outputting everything to the terminal.

Some background, I am trying to write a script that will go through a list of servers by SSH, change the password and list whether it was successful or not. I am not trying to get it to return information to the original host running the script. I am aware that the way I am doing this isn't great practice for security but the servers are on a closed network and printing it to stdout and using it in stdin isn't a huge deal as long as I clear the history.

Below is the code that I have tried. I am also trying to stop passwd from showing text. The color doesn't change on the word "successfully"

```
echo -e 'Test1\nTest1' | passwd TestUSR | grep --color 'successfully' > /dev/null 2&1
```

The below one shows a result of 0 so it is not getting the successfully thats getting printed

```
echo -e 'Test1\nTest1' | passwd TestUSR | grep -oc 'successfully'
```

I have tried passing the information to a test file for retrieval later an the file states blank. The result of the below code is 0 so grep is receiving the information.

```
echo -e 'Test1\nTest1' | passwd TestUSR > test.txt; grep -oc 'successfully' test.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated because I cannot figure out how to stop the text below from showing on the screen, and then reading it to list an easier message for the user to read. And yes they all show up on the same line in the terminal (tested on ubuntu 18.4 and parrot OS)

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `grep` for this, but the [exit status](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html#EXIT_VALUES) of `passwd`. It's a lot easier to check than text (even if `passwd` output could be redirected the same way other programs' output can), and it gives more useful information.

Comment: (If you must do redirection instead of exit status for some reason, I'd try running it inside `script`, which creates a pseudoterminal for `passwd` so it works just like it would regularly)

Comment: I shouldn't have any issues using an exit status, but I have never done that. Do you know a way of hiding the output also? I am thinking that I can have it run in the background sleep long enough for it to run, and then somehow check the exit code before leaving the ssh session?

Comment: Daniel H. Thanks for the information. I pushed the output of the command to `&>/dev/null` Then check the return status of both a successful and unsuccessful code (0 or 10) respectively. Thanks for the help